# Есть ли русские аналоги Montserrat Alternates font?

Tags: веб-дизайн, photoshop

Люблю этот шрифт [Montserrat Alternates](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat+Alternates), но не могу найти похожей кириллицы, возможно кто-то встречал?

Comment: А чем не устраивает та кириллица, которая уже присутствует в этом шрифте?

Comment: @UladzimirPalekh, вопрос задавался в 16-м году и тогда кириллицу  Montserrat сложно было найти

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Шрифт **'Montserrat Alternates'** с некоторого времени поддерживает и кирилицу. Для использования в вебе его можно найти в списке [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/?query=Montse&selection.family=Montserrat:300,400,600&selection.subset=cyrillic).

Использование:

```css
p {
  font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat+Alternates:400,500i&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">

<p>
  Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также сложившаяся структура организации в значительной степени обуславливает создание новых предложений. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации существенных финансовых и административных условий.
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi dicta, impedit reprehenderit cum! Corporis sint, ipsa excepturi, in amet quod.
</p>
```